# error message not displayed using html:errors in struts 1.3.10

Tags: struts-1, struts-validation

In JSP page having one textbox `name` and button `Login`

```
<html:form action="login">
    <html:text property="name"/>
    <html:submit value="Login" />
</html:form>
<html:errors/>
```

and in StructsActionForm has `validate()` method like

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    if (getName() == null || getName().length() < 1) {
        errors.add("name", new ActionMessage("error.name.required"));
                // TODO: add 'error.name.required' key to your resources
    }
            return errors;
}
```

if textbox `name` has an empty input when `Login` clicks it should show the error message `error.name.required` with the help of `<html:errors/>`, but it not showing the error message.

> I am using  Net-beans 8.0, Struts 1.3.10.

Pls help me out of this problem Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if validate() method is getting called. And make sure you have also defined "error.name.required" in your resources file.

Comment: @Selva Can you share the `action` configuration (`struts-config.xml`)?

Comment: @Susie Thanks sir i found it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just missed the value of the key in

> ApplicationResource.properties

so i cant able to get the error details.just add the value and i got the answer while running the program.

Thanks for the reply..